# How to update table from JSON flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flow-files with the below structure

```
{
  "PN" : "U0-WH",
  "INPUT_DATE" : "44252.699895833335",
  "LABEL" : "Marker",
  "STATUS" : "Approved",
}
```

and I need to execute an update statement using some fields

```
update table1 set column1 = 'value' where pn=${PN}
```

I found `convertJsonToSQL` but am not sure how to use it in this case

Comment: It's not clear what your question is....how does your SQL relate to the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a processor namely **ConvertjSONToSQL**. Using this you can convert your json into an update query.

[ConvertjSONToSQL Description](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html)

It takes the following parameters :

**1. JDBC Connection Pool :** Create a JDBC pool which takes DB connection information as input.

**2. Statement Type :** Here you need to provide type of statement you want to create. In your case its 'UPDATE'.

**3. Table Name :** Name of the table for which update query needed to be created

**4. Schema Name :** Name of the schema of your database.

**5. Translate Field Names :** If true, the Processor will attempt to translate JSON field names into the appropriate column names for the table specified. If false, the JSON field names must match the column names exactly, or the column will not be updated

**6. Unmatched Field Behaviour :** if an incoming JSON element has a field that does not map to any of the database table's columns, this property specifies how to handle the situation

**7. Unmatched Column Behaviour :** If an incoming JSON element does not have a field mapping for all of the database table's columns, this property specifies how to handle the situation

**8. Update Keys :** A comma-separated list of column names that uniquely identifies a row in the database for UPDATE statements. If the Statement Type is UPDATE and this property is not set, the table's Primary Keys are used. In this case, if no Primary Key exists, the conversion to SQL will fail if Unmatched Column Behaviour is set to FAIL. This property is ignored if the Statement Type is INSERT
Supports Expression Language: true (will be evaluated using flow file attributes and variable registry)

Read the description above and try to use the properties given. Detailed description of the processor is given in the link.
[ConvertjSONToSQL Description](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html)